# Dock overlays on windows

Tags: gnome, dock

I am using Ubuntu 23.04 and found that the desktop dock will overlay on windows, see image below:

[image]

The dock bar is displayed on top of bash window!  Note that:

1. I have switched **OFF** dock auto-hiding.
2. Whenever an application is launched, or I manually maximize its window, the behavior is always correct, i.e., the maximized window will be aligned to the right of the dock bar edge
3. If I switch over applications, sometime already maximized window will extend **below** the dock bar!  I don't know when this happens, but it is very common, any maximized window will behave like this!

I think it is a bug, unless there is a hidden GNOME setting to control this behavior?

Comment: It's a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1961508 Here's a workaround: https://github.com/popov895/dash-to-dock-workaround